# Best way to find the entropy of an EXE file?

Tags: disassembly, pe, entropy

I want to write a script to extract the entropy of each sections of an EXE file. What is the best tool that I can use to do this?
I tried Ghidra but it doesn't have an entropy API which I can use.

Comment: You are looking for script or just a tool to calculate entropy?

Comment: @morsisko I am looking for a script to save the output of the entropy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `r2` to get the data and `r2pipe` to script it.

`iS entropy` produce the entropy values for each section. Adding `j` will produce it in JSON format and scripting it with `r2pipe` is easy.

```
import r2pipe
p = r2pipe.open('<path_to_exe>')
res = p.cmdj('iSj entropy')
print([(x['name'],x['entropy']) for x in res['sections']])
```

> [('.text', '6.00602992'), ('.rdata', '3.94265366'), ('.data', '6.85876398'), ('.pdata', '3.46591559'), ('.rsrc', '4.70150326'), ('.reloc', '4.96848447')]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I wanted.
For some weird reason I am getting a keyerror when I try to print the entropy.
If I remove x['entropy'] from your code, I get the section names.

Comment: try printing the whole `x` and see what properties are available - one of them should be the entropy

Comment: When I just print res or x as you mentioned, I can see the entropy values for each section, but it shows a keyerror when I try to just get the entropy value

Comment: well, keyerror means there's no such entry and since there is such entry maybe there's a subtle typo? hard to guess w/o actual code

Comment: I  realized why I am getting the error. The radare didn't calculate the entropy of .bss section of the file.
`{'name': '.bss', 'size': 0, 'vsize': 4096, 'perm': '-rw-', 'paddr': 0, 'vaddr': 4214784}`
That is why it shows a keyerror

Comment: interesting. Are you on latest version of `r2`?

Comment: I'm using version 4.3.1 for Windows. (not the latest, I'll try updating it)